# Proving identity for $\Bbb Q\setminus \{1\}$ with operation $a*b=a+b-ab$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, irrational-numbers

> The set of all rational numbers other than $1$ forms a commutative group with respect to the operation $*$ defined by $$a * b = a + b - ab$$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{1\}$.

How do I verify that

$$( a * b )^{-1} = a^{-1} * b^{-1}?$$

Comment: Follows immediately by *transport of structure* as in the linked dupe.

Comment: You can just use associativity and commutativity to prove it directly (i.e. consider $(a*b)*(a^{-1}*b^{-1})$)